# Set C# Picturebox Container

Tags: c#, winforms, picturebox

I am creating a Windows form with `PictureBox`controls and need to know the location of them relative to the form. I want to change their container to the form, but they must remain on top of the `Panel` controls they are already in. Is there a way to set the container of the pictureboxes through code?

Comment: Invest your time in WPF; winforms is deprecated.

Comment: Thanks, that was so helpful . . . *not really*

Comment: Regardless of what you think now, you will eventually convert to WPF. I was once an avid Winforms types of person, used it for everything. Once I tried WPF though, I never went back. If you don't understand now, you certainly will later, and when that happens you should revisit this post.

Comment: Not really. I can do anything WPF does with WinForm or ASP.net

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What are you asking for can be done by setting the control [`Parent`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.parent(v=vs.110).aspx) property and then calling [`BringToFront`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.bringtofront(v=vs.110).aspx) method.

However changing the parent will also change the treatment of the control location, so in order to keep it in its original location, you need to know the relative location to the form. Which returns you back to the original question.

The relative location of a control to the form can be deteremined by using [`PointToScreen`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.pointtoscreen%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and [`PointToClient`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.pointtoclient(v=vs.110).aspx) methods like this:

```
public static class ControlUtils
{
    public static Point GetFormLocation(this Control control)
    {
        return control.FindForm().PointToClient(control.PointToScreen(control.Location));
    }
}
```

so you can use

```
var formLocation = pictureBox.GetFormLocation();
```

anytime you need to know to know the relative location of your picture boxes to the form.

If that's all you needed, I would suggest you not changing their container. But in case you still want to do that, you can use something like this:

```
var location = pictureBox.PointToScreen(pictureBox.Location);
pictureBox.Parent = pictureBox.FindForm();
pictureBox.Location = pictureBox.Parent.PointToClient(location);
pictureBox.BringToFront();
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I will try this.

Comment: The code has worked very well. Unfortunately, the panels are now covering the pictureboxes. Is there any way to fix this?

Comment: I don't know other way than `BringToFront`.